# When is the conditional information of a partition equals to zero?

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability, information-theory, ergodic-theory

For the discussion below, let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a probability measure. Let $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{B}$ be a sub-sigma-algebra. Let $\alpha$ be a partition of $X$ to  countably-many disjoint, measurable sets.

I'm reading W. Parry's "Topics in Ergodic Theory". The author introduces the concepts of "Information of a partition of a probability space" and "Entropy of a partition". I've attached the relevant definition in the end of the post.

A few sentences afterward, he mentions:

> As easily seen, $H(\xi|\mathcal{A})=0$ (or $I(\xi|\mathcal{A}) \equiv 0$) if and only if $\xi$ consists of $\mathcal{A}$ sets.

I'm having two issues with the last quote.

1. I'm not entirely sure what "Consist of $\mathcal{A}$ sets" means. I think it means $\xi\subset \mathcal{A}$, but I'm not confident with it.
2. Under the assumption that $\xi \subset \mathcal A$ is indeed the author's intention, I don't see why this is correct. If I'm not mistaken, we'd have:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   I(\xi|\mathcal{A})(x) &= - \sum_{A\in \mathcal{A}}1_A (x) \cdot \log (\mu (A|\mathcal{A})) \\
   &= - \log(\mu (A_0 | \mathcal{A}))
   \end{align}
   $$
   Where $x\in A_0$. It is not clear to me why the conditional measure is one in that case. I'd be glad for clarifications on that. **Edit - There's a mistake in the last expression. See correction bellow.**

**Definition - Conditional Information:**

We define $I(\alpha | \mathcal{A})$ to be the measurable function:
$$
\begin{align}
I(\alpha | \mathcal{A}) &: X \to \mathbb{R} \ \ \ s.t. \\
&I(\alpha | \mathcal{A}) = - \sum_{A\in \alpha} 1_A \cdot \log(\mu(A|\mathcal{A}))
\end{align}
$$

**EDIT**:

In the calculation for $I(\xi | \mathcal{A}) $ I was using the wrong definition. We should have:

$$
\begin{align}
I(\xi|\mathcal{A})(x) &= - \sum_{A\in \xi}1_A (x) \cdot \log (\mu (A|\mathcal{A})) \\
&= - \log(\mu (A_0 | \mathcal{A}))
\end{align}
$$

Where $A_0 \in \xi $, and **not** $A_0 \in \mathcal A$.
Under this correction, I think the desired claim is now reduced to:
$$
\begin{align}
    &\mu (A_0 | \mathcal{A}) = 1 \\
\iff &A_0 \in \mathcal A 
\end{align}
$$

I still can't see why is it true.